# how to change color of elements one by one using javascript(jquery) and then reset the result again one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to change color of elements one by one using javascript(jquery) and then reset the result again one by one 
    
                .cub {
                    background: aqua;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    display: inline-block;
                }

Comment: What do you mean by one by one? do you want some delay in between changing color?

Comment: <div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>

Comment: What if change color for all at once? is it ok?

Comment: no, one by one and then  return the previous color one by one

Comment: i have four blocks  <div class="cub"></div>
        <div class="cub"></div>
        <div class="cub"></div>
        <div class="cub"></div>

Comment: You want to change the color of all 4 blocks at once on pressing some button etc?

Comment: it can be setInterval or button, it doesn't matter, but elements must change color one by one

Comment: Oh, well you said it yourself... use `setInterval` - have you tried that?

Comment: What do you mean by `one by one`? you always explain by saying `one by one`?

Comment: OP means like light bulbs, first one div is highlighted, then second also, then first three. And once all are highlighted, last one turns off, then second last etc.

Comment: Mohit Bhardwaj yes, exactly

Comment: well, I'm trying to write some logic for it, if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class and remove class using `jQuery`. First assign another class to these divs so no other divs will be affected.

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

var counter = 0;
var divs = $('.box'), div = null;
setInterval(function(){
  div = $(divs[counter]);
  if(div.hasClass('cub')){
     div.removeClass('cub');
  } else {
    div.addClass('cub');
  }
  counter = (counter + 1) % 4;
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code if it works. I was not able to check it but it should work.

```
<div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>
<div class="cub"></div>

.cub{ background-color: white; }
.cub.highlighted{ background-color: aqua; }

    <script>
      var highlighting = true;

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var highlightingInterval = setInterval(function(){
          if( $(".cub.highlighted").length == 0 )
            highlighting = true;
          else if( $(".cub.highlighted").length == 4 )
            highlighting = false;

          if( highlighting )
          {
            $(".cub").not(".highlighted").eq(0).addClass("highlighted");
          }
          else
          {
            var targetIndex = $(".cub.highlighted").length - 1;                                  $(".cub.highlighted").eq(targetIndex).removeClass("highlighted");
          }
        }, 2000 );//setInterval
      });//document ready
    </script>
```

Comment: can you explain please this counter = (counter + 1) % 4; why it doesn't work without % 4?

Comment: Using `%4` ensures that the result is always the remainder of division by 4. Actually, it limits the result of increment from going above 3. e.g. if counter is 3, in next iteration it will become 3 + 1 = 4, which might break the loop, which I think should go from 0 to 3. Now, if we have `%` there, it makes 4 as 0 ( 4 % 4 = 0 ).